# Symfony Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException at session_start()

Tags: php, symfony

I've been getting this error: `REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Warning: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString'" at C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\ALM\ALM-proto\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php line 153` whenever I run my symfony server. It prevents my localhost:8000 page from loading. I've opened the file from the error message and found out that this block of code is the culprit. By commenting it out, I no longer see the error, and the page loads. However, because I don't have access to the session, it causes other problems. So I need this block of code of code to work. How can I fix this?

```
if (!session_start()) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to start the session');
}
```

Here are my Symfony project specs:

- Symfony 4.3.11
- PHP 7.4.16
- Composer 2.0.11
- OS: Windows 10

Comment: What version of Ramsey\Uuid?

Comment: ramsey/uuid 4.1.1